# Creating extent indicator in Data View of ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, extents, bookmarks

I know how to create an extent indicator in Layout View, but I have no idea how to create one for Data View. I have 25 bookmarks created for Data View and what I need to do is to display all of them in Data View. I work in ArcMap 10.3.

Comment: create a polygon feature class, zoom in to bookmark, draw a polygon around the extent, and repeat

Comment: alternatively use graphics rather than a polygon feature class

Answer (score 0):

The [ListBookmarks function documentation](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/listbookmarks.htm) includes:

> **ListBookmarks example 3**
>
> This sample will convert each bookmark in a map document to a feature.

A copy/paste of that sample with some minor edits to match your environment should enable you to draw the extents of all your bookmarks in Data View (and Layout View).